# How do you clear NSManagedObjectContext cache?

Tags: core-data, icloud, nsfetchrequest

I am running into an issue where I am using iCloud and CoreData. When I update my core data database on one device, iCloud syncs the data to my second device correctly.

However, lets say I have the app running on both devices before I make the core data change. My second device has already made an NSFetchRequest (lets say its called fetchRequest1). After the import from iCloud was successful on my second device, calling the same request again from fetchRequest1 returns the all of my new data (anything that was inserted) but does not contain any updates to entities that had previously existed.

It seems like something is being cached oddly, since if I close the application and re-open it everything shows up correctly. In addition, if I make the fetch request and loop through each entity and call the NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject method on each one, then the data shows up! This however is obviously not always ideal, as a large database would not be able to handle this.

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue, or a way to flush the cache for fetch requests on a NSManagedObjectContext object?